# In typescript, how can I specify a type based on its properties, not an interface?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, I want to run some code on an object that I know will have two properties, `includeUnassignedLocations` and `contractStatusCodes` (which have the types `KnockoutObservable<boolean>` and `KnockoutObservableArray<number>` respectively). There are various different classes which could be used, but I don't want to make them all implement an interface because they're all quite different from each other. Is there a way to get typescript to check that any object passed into the method has these properties on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can rely on the implicit interface of the object.

Let's say that you have a class named `MyKnockoutClass` with `includeUnassignedLocations` and `contractStatusCodes` in it. You have also defined a `MyKnockoutInterface` with those two properties. Even if the class doesn't implement explicitly the interface, it still implements it implicitly. So anything that expects a `MyKnockoutInterface` type will work with `MyKnockoutClass`.

```
class MyKnockoutClass {
    includeUnassignedLocations: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    contractStatusCodes: KnockoutObservableArray<number>;
}

interface MyKnockoutInterface {
    includeUnassignedLocations: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    contractStatusCodes: KnockoutObservableArray<number>;
}

function doSomething(object: MyKnockoutInterface) {
}

var object = new MyKnockoutClass();
doSomething(object);
```

Comment: I think this sounds like better practice than the solution I'd posted, thanks. It's certainly neater syntax, and having an interface name means it's easier to articulate what the properties are for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify a type with object literal notation, instead of an interface. The following code will give a typescript error if the result of `getMyObject()` does not have the two properties, or if the properties themselves have the wrong types.

```
var myObject: { 
    //this can be any type which implements these properties
    includeUnassignedLocations: KnockoutObservable<boolean>,
    contractStatusCodes: KnockoutObservableArray<number>;
};

myObject = getMyObject();

//do something with myObject here, safe in the knowledge it has those two properties
```